# Text Progress Bar in Python3.8

Tags: python-3.8

```
import time

def create_logs():
        print("Creating log file...")
        print("Process [", end="")
        for i in range(0,5):
                time.sleep(1)
                print("#", end="")
        logs = open('/home/motya/Desktop/logs_py/logs.txt', 'w')
        logs.write("LOGS_ENABLE=1\nUSERNAME=GUEST")
        logs.close
        for i in range(0,5):
                time.sleep(1)
                print("#",end="")
        print("]\nComplete!\n")

def start_welcome():
        create_logs()
        print("Welcome!")

start_welcome()
```

When i'm using the end parameter in print(), the output occurs after 10 seconds (the sum of all time.sleep). When the end parameter is deleted, the output occurs every second, as it should be, but with a new line.
How can i fix it?

upd: sorry for my english, it's not my main language and it`s difficult for me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adding `sys.stdout.flush()` after your print statements like this:

```
import time
import sys

def create_logs():
        print("Creating log file...")
        print("Process [", end="")
        for i in range(0,5):
                time.sleep(1)
                print("#", end="")
                sys.stdout.flush()
        logs = open('/home/motya/Desktop/logs_py/logs.txt', 'w')
        logs.write("LOGS_ENABLE=1\nUSERNAME=GUEST")
        logs.close
        for i in range(0,5):
                time.sleep(1)
                print("#",end="")
                sys.stdout.flush()
        print("]\nComplete!\n")
        sys.stdout.flush()

def start_welcome():
        create_logs()
        print("Welcome!")
        sys.stdout.flush()

start_welcome()
```

That will cause your print to do it's job and then flush the output to the screen.